# Designer cannot be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designd

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

First off, I am aware there are an abundance of questions on this specific error on SO, however none of their solutions are particularly feasible for me (such as ensuring the use of a particular .NET version)

I have a few classes, which do not throw a warning. Here's one of them (they're all just empty shells at the moment)

```
using Infrastructure.Common.Controls;

namespace WorkSpace.Accounts
{
    public interface ICtlAccountsContacts
    {}

    public partial class CtlAccountsContacts : BoundControl, ICtlAccountsContacts
    {
        public CtlAccountsContacts()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

This class however, does throw the warning in the title.

```
using Infrastructure.Common.Controls;

namespace WorkSpace.Accounts
{
    public interface ICtlAccountsInternational
    {}

    public partial class CtlAccountsInternational : BoundControl, ICtlAccountsInternational
    {
        public CtlAccountsInternational()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

`BoundControl` is a custom class that inherits from DevExpress' `XtraUserControl`, which inherits from `System.Windows.Forms.UserControl` so I don't see why I should be able to view one control in Design view and not the other.

They're part of the same project, and like I said same namespace. I've tried all sorts of combinations of Build, Rebuild, rebooting... Everything I can think of. Still get that warning.

Comment: Have you tried creating a new class and copy pasting the old code into it? or if that doesn't help a new project?- I had similar 'weird' issues sometimes in VS and the only thing that helped me, was creating a new project and copying the old code. which makes one wonder which config file is fubared

Comment: I'll try simply scrapping the control and starting over... Unfortunately a new project is out of the question. The project is quite large, just started adding some new stuff to it and it's behaving strangely.

Comment: I don't know if this helps you, but from my experience Visual Studio sometimes has trouble showing the designer if the designer class is not the first class in .cs file. It makes no sense, but try declaring your interface underneath the class declaration, or maybe even in a separate file. We had to use a similar approach when deriving our user controls from a templated base class (also XtraUserControl).

Comment: @sab669 oh okay, Then thats out of the question, i thought you were just starting out with some code containers to fill :) - anyways good luck